# Remove IMAGE_DEBUG_DIRECTORY from .rdata section

Tags: c++, visual-c++, portable-executable

How can I remove IMAGE_DEBUG_DIRECTORY data from `.rdata` section of PE?

I am using MS Visual Studio 2015. I did check almost all compile options of project properties. But IMAGE_DEBUG_DIRECTORY data still exists in my output executable file...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can do this by set undocumented Linker Option **`/EMITPOGOPHASEINFO`**. so go to linker command line and insert this string (**`/EMITPOGOPHASEINFO`**) in additional options. this option suppress pgo ([Profile-Guided Optimizations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7k32f4k.aspx)) section in pe

read also : [Pogo aka PGO aka Profile Guided Optimization](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2008/11/12/pogo/) and [Walkthrough: Using Profile-Guided Optimizations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xct6db7f.aspx)

and of course you must not Generate Debug Info - use [`/DEBUG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/debug-generate-debug-info) linker option - so sure that no `/DEBUG` option in linker command line. or alternatively use `/DEBUG:NONE /EMITPOGOPHASEINFO` combination - in this case must not be `IMAGE_DEBUG_DIRECTORY` in pe file

Comment: Omg! Thanks. I learned a lot from you. With the `/EMITPOGOPHASEINFO` compilation option, I could remove `IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_` data from `.rdata` section. But `IMAGE_DEBUG_DIRECTORY` data still exists...

Comment: @ChangUk - are you use [`/DEBUG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/debug-generate-debug-info) linker option ? I assume that you remove it - it well known. you must remove it - must not be `/DEBUG` in command line. or `/DEBUG:NONE /EMITPOGOPHASEINFO`

Comment: I set 'No' at "Linker > Debugging > Generate Debug Info" property... In spite of absence of `/DEBUG` option, `IMAGE_DEBUG_DIRECTORY` data is still alive...

Comment: @ChangUk - copy-paste your exactly linker command line. must not be `IMAGE_DEBUG_DIRECTORY` if you not use `/DEBUG` and use `/EMITPOGOPHASEINFO`

Comment: Oh! I've found a solution at last! I changed some linker options: from `/OPT:REF` to `/OPT:NOREF` and from `/LTCG:incremental` to `/LTCG`. Then, works well. I took a hint from 'Profile-Guided Optimizations' you said. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ChangUk - yes, `/OPT:NOREF` and `/LTCG` typical for release build. whrn your initial option related to debug build

Comment: This answer is no longer correct, should be unmarked.

Comment: @IgorLevicki this is not true. `/EMITPOGOPHASEINFO` still work . incorrect only your answer

Comment: @RbMm https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-Studio-2022-C-linker-14333162/10126401

Comment: @IgorLevicki and so what ?

Comment: @RbMm You seem to think that you are smarter than everyone else, I am sure you can figure it out yourself.

Comment: @IgorLevicki i already say , that on all link.exe versions which i use ( higest is not 14.36.32532.0 ) all is ok. PE not corrupted. If you think that on some link version exist bug , share this version ( link.exe and it DLLs). And URL which you paste here, not containing any additional/useful info. As result i and asked - and so what ?

Comment: @RbMm The URL gives you bug details and the linker version number with which I first encountered it. How would you know if your PE is corrupted or not without knowing what to check? Being able to run PE != PE not corrupted.

Comment: @IgorLevicki at this url no any details. only the same your statement about error. *without knowing what to check?* - ha-ha. i know what to check. i have expert level knowledge here. and i nothing say about "run" PE. i from self side say that *14.36.32532.0* work correct with `/EMITPOGOPHASEINFO`. so if was error in some link versions, probably it already fixed. upload linker binaries, which wrong handle `/EMITPOGOPHASEINFO` and i check it. all what need - link.exe and related dlls. but not your some src(for what ?) or explain what to check (i know this without external help)

Comment: @IgorLevicki - found. really bug in **NumberOfSections** field. if PE not containing any own read only data (*.rdata) and we use `/EMITPOGOPHASEINFO`  - the **NumberOfSections** is `-1` from correct value. as result the last section of PE not visible (this not mandatory *.rsrc*, can be .reloc, etc). but if your PE have const/read only data - all is ok. probably if `.rdata` ( *.rdata$voltmd* ) only from PGO the linker by mistake not count it in case `EMITPOGOPHASEINFO` option. but *.rdata* still exist

Comment: @IgorLevicki [/EMITVOLATILEMETADATA:NO](https://twitter.com/alexsho71327477/status/1685720999910662144)

Comment: @IgorLevicki so bug at all not in `/EMITPOGOPHASEINFO` (it work as excepted). bug in `/emitvolatilemetadata` option (by default it on) - with this option generated some symbol ( `__volatile_metadata` ) in `.rdata` section. but not incremented count of section. if and without this option *.rdata* exist - all is ok. but if no *.rdata* in your PE - will be wrong count of section

Comment: @IgorLevicki - without `/EMITPOGOPHASEINFO` - will be another data in .rdata section and no bug. if you have another *.rdata* - no bug. but if you have no .rdata and no pgo data (placed in .rdata) - will be bug - wrong section count

Comment: @RbMm So, do you agree now that `/EMITPGOPHASEINFO` triggers the issue under certain conditions? The reason I warned against using it is because it is internal / undocumented, and as such it has UB which can change at any time. Using `/EMITVOLATILEMETADATA:NO` just adds one more internal / undocumented switch with UB, it doesn't solve the problem. The best option is to use external tool with known correct behavior.

Comment: @IgorLevicki -no, i absolute not agree with this. `/EMITPGOPHASEINFO` not  the issue. may be you want say in this case that have no any constand data in PE triggers the issue ? issue only in `/EMITVOLATILEMETADATA` create (if it still not exist) *.rdata* section but **not incrementr section count** (if .rdata "create", not "opened" ). you wrong determinate src of issue and use wrong solution

Comment: @RbMm I do not care what exactly happens when I use `/EMITPGOPHASEINFO` -- all I care about is that the resulting PE is corrupted. If you want you can update your own answer to clarify that adding `/EMITVOLATILEMETADATA:NO` will workaround the issue, but you can't vandalize my answer because you don't like it.

Comment: @RbMm Also, people should not be encouraged to depend on internal / undocumented linker switches. Their behavior can change or they can be removed in future versions. Proper solution is using a 3rd party tool, or writing your own PE rebuilder.

Comment: @IgorLevicki i explain what is happens internally. what way is use - everybody can decide by self

Comment: @RbMm And my answer explains how to reliably remove `IMAGE_DEBUG_DIRECTORY` using a 3rd party tool without corrupting PE file. It is totally irrelevant what happens internally when you use UNDOCUMENTED and UNSUPPORTED linker options.

Comment: @IgorLevicki look like you nothing understand at all. `/EMITPGOPHASEINFO` not corrupt PE file and perfect work with any linker version

Comment: @RbMm Looks like you are more of a hacker than a programmer. Real programmers do not use undocumented options and APIs and don't advise others to do so.

Comment: @IgorLevicki think that this not related to topic.

Answer (score -1):

As of Visual Studio 2022 version 17.3 this workaround no longer works because it produces corrupt executable (`IMAGE_RESOURCE_DIRECTORY` entry is invalid and neither Windows Explorer nor resource manipulation tools can find the `.rsrc` section even though it is still present in the file).

The workaround is to use the [CFF Exlporer](https://ntcore.com/?page_id=388) from the Explorer Suite. Despite claiming it's version III, it is actually version VIII, only the standalone CFF Explorer is older than the one bundled in the Suite.

Once you have installed the suite, removing the `IMAGE_DEBUG_DIRECTORY` is really easy.

- Right-click the executable, select **Open with CFF Explorer** from the context menu

  [image: CFF Explorer]
- Click on Data Directories in the left pane
- Right-click on Debug Directory RVA, and select Remove Debug Directory
- Click File then Save As... and save under a new name

**Important:** Make sure you thoroughly test the new executable before replacing the original.

Comment: visual studio only integrated shell editor and unrelated here at all. It’s ignorant to write about the studio version in this context. you can only write about linker version. i dont know why you got "corrupt" image and strong doubt that /EMITPOGOPHASEINFO related to this. how minimum with 14.36.32532.0 link.exe version all is ok

Comment: It is not ignorant to say that the latest linker version shipping with specific VS version (17.3 and higher) now has different behavior. It is ignorant to assume that I have not made a reproducible test case for the issue before writing about it here.

Comment: ignorant write about vs version, but not about linker version